# Which Aspect/Interceptor handles the @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations, interceptor

Does anyone know which class handles the @Transactional annotation? I am searching for the source code that creates the transaction, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TransactionInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html) handles the interception logic, but obviously with the assistance of a lot of other infrastructure classes. That's the best place to start, though. The transaction sync stuff is pretty fearsome when you start getting into the source code.

The processing of `@Transactional`, and its parsing into the neutral transaction descriptor object model, is done by [`AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.html).

Answer (score 4):

I've done a deep code analysis for the @Transactional stuff here: http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/spring-transactional-explained/

Be carefull, this analysis only focus on JPA transaction. I did not consider datasources other than database but I guess the approach is similar